# Well ordered set similar to an ordinal is an ordinal?

Tags: set-theory, ordinals

I'm wondering if a well-ordered set $B$ which is similar to an ordinal $A$ is necessarily an ordinal ?

I think it may be not as the $\in$ relation in the ordinal number does not necessarily be the counter-party order defined in $B$, so therefore $B$ need not be an ordinal. However, I can't think of an example to this. Moreover, the structure on an ordinal number is so special that maybe every well-ordered set similar to it should also be ordinal.

Thank you for your enlightment (and some examples/instruction of proof if possible)!

Comment: What do you mean by “similar”?

Comment: @RobertShore: Hi, i mean 2 well-ordered set are similar if there exists an order-preserving bijective function $f : A \to B$.

Comment: So by "similar" you mean "order-isomorphic". The answer is "no". To construct a counterexample, think of the finite ordinals. [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391) + [please avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933).

Comment: @AnneBauval: Thanks for your comment, could you please be more specific if possible ? I don't understand what do you mean.

Comment: Give me first some finite ordinal $\ne\varnothing.$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.  *Any* set with a single element is well ordered and order-isomorphic to $1$, but not all single-element sets are ordinals.